# Countdown animation class works differently on some devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I'm using the below Java class (Found on the web) as a countdown timer circle animation, The issue is that on some devices like Huawei Mate 10 Pro & Huawei G8 the animation finishes sooner than it is supposed to while on the other couple of devices that I've tested its working perfectly.
For example on Mate 10 pro, when I call the class to start the timer with '10' as the parameter (circle animation supposed to be completed in 10 seconds but it goes faster and finishes in exactly half the time-5 seconds!-) while in another device with same Android version (Android 10) it's working perfectly (Completes in 10 seconds).
So I figured the android version is not the problem here, Any idea what may be the issue ??

```
package com.maxwellforest.blogtimer;
import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;

import com.borsam.bleexample.R;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Countdown timer view.
 *
 * @author Mike Gouline
 */
public class TimerView extends View {

    private static final int ARC_START_ANGLE = 270; // 12 o'clock

    private static final float THICKNESS_SCALE = 0.03f;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;

    private RectF mCircleOuterBounds;
    private RectF mCircleInnerBounds;

    private Paint mCirclePaint;
    private Paint mEraserPaint;

    private float mCircleSweepAngle;

    private ValueAnimator mTimerAnimator;

    public TimerView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public TimerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TimerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        int circleColor = R.color.colorPrimary;

        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TimerView);
            if (ta != null) {
                circleColor = ta.getColor(R.styleable.TimerView_circleColor, circleColor);
                ta.recycle();
            }
        }

        mCirclePaint = new Paint();
        mCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mCirclePaint.setColor(circleColor);

        mEraserPaint = new Paint();
        mEraserPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mEraserPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mEraserPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("SuspiciousNameCombination")
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec); // Trick to make the view square
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            mBitmap.eraseColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
        }

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        updateBounds();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);

        if (mCircleSweepAngle > 0f) {
            mCanvas.drawArc(mCircleOuterBounds, ARC_START_ANGLE, mCircleSweepAngle, true, mCirclePaint);
            mCanvas.drawOval(mCircleInnerBounds, mEraserPaint);
        }

        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void start(int secs) {
        stop();

        mTimerAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f);
        mTimerAnimator.setDuration(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(secs));//(secs*1000);
        mTimerAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        mTimerAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                drawProgress((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
            }
        });
        mTimerAnimator.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (mTimerAnimator != null && mTimerAnimator.isRunning()) {
            mTimerAnimator.cancel();
            mTimerAnimator = null;

            drawProgress(0f);
        }
    }

    private void drawProgress(float progress) {
        mCircleSweepAngle = 360 * progress;

        invalidate();
    }

    private void updateBounds() {
        final float thickness = getWidth() * THICKNESS_SCALE;

        mCircleOuterBounds = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        mCircleInnerBounds = new RectF(
                mCircleOuterBounds.left + thickness,
                mCircleOuterBounds.top + thickness,
                mCircleOuterBounds.right - thickness,
                mCircleOuterBounds.bottom - thickness);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that all your code? What about `onTouch(MotionEvent)`?

Comment: @Darkman It is all the class code, It does not have any onTouch method, you just call the class with its object like "timerView.start(10)" and the animated circle starts to be drawn within 10 seconds. The thing I am most confused about is that it is working correctly on some devices, while not working correctly on some other devices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an option in Developer options "Animator duration scale", by default this value is 1x if they are different for devices then you may experience slower or faster animations based on the value set.